# How to get info about System Device Profiles (MDM) on MacOS?

Tags: macos, configuration-profiles, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

[image]

I need to get information about **System Device Profiles (MDM or enrollment)**, such as Details: Description, control the computer, Allows and other.
But I need to get it from some *FileInfo* in order to write these info to my .txt file.

I found the right information in **/Library/Application Support/com.Apple.TCC/MDMOverrides.plist** . But in new system Mac version these info is SIP protected, that's why I need to restart the PC in Recovery Mode and write the next console command: *csrutil disable* . I need to find an easier solution, which is approached with any version of system.

I can also find the necessary information in System Preferences/Profiles in Details, so does it mean that the information is opened? Where can I find it?
It can be no path in Privacy Preferences Policy Control.

I have also known about console commands such as *profiles list* or *profiles show*/, but it isn't full info.

I really need to read the full info about **all Mobile Device Management** profiles from some file in order to write in my own file and send to server, or something like this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You lost me at the end “profiles from some file in order to write in my own file and send to server, or something like this” - are you writing your own MDM - how are you measuring full info? You may need to get on the sending MDM for what I consider full info, since you don’t even get certificates until after the MDM profile pushes over the wire...

Comment: @bmike I need to get info about profiles on my Mac from other different PC. Maybe, I can download the file with full info about permissions, settings. description, type, certificate, control the computer. But where can I find it? (Condition: I can't get the  MDMOverrides.plist ).

Comment: @bmike maybe I can import file like this? But where can I find the info?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see profiles in detail resort to the command line tool `profiles`. You need to run the command with admin privileges to get info about system profiles though.

This command will show all installed profiles in XML. You can use xmllint or your programming languages XML functionality to parse for the information you are searching.

```
sudo /usr/bin/profiles list -output stdout-xml
```