# Howto remove an imported Network Configuration profile from MacOS 10.15.7 without using GUI?

Tags: network, dns, configuration-profiles

In order to get a useful DNS over TLS server configuration on macOS, I imported a network profile. After having installed this network configuration file, I did not see any new entry in the Network Settings graphical user interface. Only in the terminal, I can see it seems to be active:

```
profiles list
[user[1] attribute: profileIdentifier: com.quad9.tsecuredecs.HASH]
There are 1 user configuration profiles installed for 'user'.
```

In all tutorials on how to remove custom Network profiles, I see it appears in the GUI (for example [Can't delete NextDNS profile from macOS Network Preferences](https://help.nextdns.io/t/g9hf600/cant-delete-nextdns-profile-from-macos-network-preferences)). But in mine, there is nothing else than the default ones.

[image: Screenshot of Network settings showing only Wi-Fi, ProtonVPN, an Bluetooth PAN services]

Comment: Profiles are in System Preferences [Settings, Ventura] > Profiles. if you have no profiles this won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, inspired by [stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412576/how-to-get-info-about-system-device-profiles-mdm-on-macos):

In the System Preferences GUI, the network configuration profile does not appear under "Network" but under "User profiles" - see screenshot.
[image: screenshot]